# Assigning range values to a data table

Tags: python

Suppose I have two strings of 6 values (think of them as lower and upper bound limits of coordinates):

```
lo_values = c(1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
hi_values = c(9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 60)
```

and suppose I have a data table with 6 columns consisting of 3 possible values (B, L, T):

```
row1 = c(T, L, L, L, T, B)
row2 = c(B, B, B, T, T, T)
```

etc...

I would like to write a script that uses the lo_ and hi_values and assign them to each row based on the inputs in the data table. So for example, row1 would be:

```
row1 -> (1-9 = T, 10-39 = L, 40-49 = T, 50-60 = B)
```

Similarly, row2 would be:

```
row2 -> (1-29 = B, 30-60 = T).
```

I'm having a hard time thinking of an appropriate way to program this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points first. In python strings are for text. What you mean by strings are either tuples or lists. A list is an ordered list of objects. In python it is represented like so `a = [1,2,3,4]` so a is a list of 4 numbers. A tuple is like a list but it is immutable, once created it can not be modified. You'd need to make a new copy with changes if you wanted a different version.

Having said that, I think I understand what you want(but correct me if I understood anything incorrectly). This code should do for your example:

```
lo_values = (1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50) # this a tuple
hi_values = (9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 60) # this too

rows = [ ('T', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'T', 'B'),
         ('B', 'B', 'B', 'T', 'T', 'T')] # rows is a list containing 2 tuples, one with each row

for row in rows:
    result = []
    previous_value = row[0]
    run_start = 0
    for i in range(1, len(row)):
        value = row[i]
        if value != previous_value:
            lower_bound = lo_values[run_start]
            upper_bound = hi_values[i-1]
            result.append((lower_bound, upper_bound, previous_value))
            run_start = i
        previous_value = value
    lower_bound = lo_values[run_start]
    upper_bound = hi_values[-1]
    result.append((lower_bound, upper_bound, row[-1]))
    print result
```

Result of running:

```
[(1, 9, 'T'), (10, 39, 'L'), (40, 49, 'T'), (50, 60, 'B')]
[(1, 29, 'B'), (30, 60, 'T')]
```

This should get you started on how to approach the problem.

Comment: If an answer answers your question, you should accept it. That will increase the chance that people will reply to you in the future

Comment: Right, sorry. Still learning my way around here. Thanks again.